# Why direction of Ampere's Law follows right hand rule?

Tags: electromagnetism, conventions

Why direction of Ampere's Law follows right hand rule?

Comment: Related:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114496/

Answer (score 0):

Because we conventionally use a [right-handed coordinate system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Right-HandedCoordinateSystem.html).

In a [left-handed coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Orientation_and_handedness), it would follow a left-hand rule.